# an android file picker or camera for taking pictures or videos not working on nexus 4

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to open an android file picker or camera for taking pictures or videos using the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE && Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
            try {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file 
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                LogS.d("File Uri: " + uri.toString());
                // Get the path
                String path = BeanUtils.getPath(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), uri);

                AnnexFile f = new AnnexFile(path);
                if (!addedFiles.contains(f)) {
                    addFileToLayout(f);
                    addedFiles.add(f);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.you_allready_added_this_file_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogS.e(e);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.file_manager_invalid), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE && Activity.RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
            try {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                LogS.d("File Uri: " + uri.toString());
                // Get the path
                String path = BeanUtils.getPath(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), uri);

                AnnexFile f = new AnnexFile(path);
                if (!addedFiles.contains(f)) {
                    addFileToLayout(f);
                    addedFiles.add(f);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.you_allready_added_this_file_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogS.e(e);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.file_manager_invalid), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void openImageIntent() {

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam){
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    final Intent videoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    final List<ResolveInfo> listVideoCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(videoIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listVideoCam){
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(videoIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    //FileSystem
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*;video/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

The code works perfect on Samsung S4 and Sony Experia J but fails on Nexus 4 (android 5.1.1). When I debugged the application on nexus 4 I found that the following `Uri uri = data.getData();` is null if the end user tries to make a picture. The application works on all devices if the user tries to make a video or to open an existing media file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I debugged the application on nexus 4 I found that the following Uri uri = data.getData(); is null if the end user tries to make a picture

You are assuming that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` returns a result in the form of a `Uri`. It is [not documented to do so](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE). There are thousands of camera apps, pre-installed and user-installed. Many of them will advertise support for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. None have to return a `Uri` result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fixed the issue by using an imageFile field in both methods:         `intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));` and `Uri uri = data.getData();
    String path;
    if (uri == null) {
     path = imageFile.getPath();
     LogS.d("path: " + path);

    } else {
     LogS.d("File Uri: " + uri.toString());
     // Get the path
      path = BeanUtils.getPath(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), uri);    
    }`

Comment: however I have another problem now. How can I figure out which file is from android file picker and which file is from camera ?

Comment: @aurelianr: Look at the `resultCode` that you are getting in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: The results is the CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE  for all requests. I do now how to differentiate the returned result.

Comment: @aurelianr: Then use different result codes in your `startActivityForResult()` calls. After all, your `onActivityResult()` implementation shown above has code for `PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE`.

Comment: how to do that ? `chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);` I have a single `startActivityforResult` for all types of intents.

Comment: @aurelianr: "I have a single startActivityforResult for all types of intents" -- then you are going to have to change that, or you are going to have to change your expectations such that you do not care where the image is coming from.

Comment: I want to change that but I do not know how to startAnActivityforResult for each type of intent from my list of intents?

Comment: @aurelianr: AFAIK, you would have to get rid of `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`. Give the user the broad choice of where to get the image from before coming to `openImageIntent()` (camera, video, arbitrary content), and use separate `startActivityForResult()` calls for each. Or, again, change your expectations so that you can treat all three sources of data the same. Or, do not use the system-supplied chooser, but instead create your own UI, listing the matching activities, so you can put the proper code into your eventual `startActivityForResult()` call.